# Android Intent many Buttons

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying one thing: in my Activity I have 30 buttons inside them for everyone there is a number that goes from 1 to 30. Now I want to assign each an Intent that opens the same Activity but passing the corresponding number. How can I do?

```
public void ApriTavolo(View v) {
     Bundle extras = new Bundle();

     // pass the value of button           
     extras.putString("one", one);

     // Perform action on click   
     Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interno_tavolo.class);
     activityChangeIntent.putExtras(extras);
     startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could dod something like

```
String pressed = null;
switch(v.getId()) {
 case R.id.firstButton:
   pressed = "one";
   break;
// up to the end
}

Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interno_tavolo.class);
 extras.putString("one", one);
activityChangeIntent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
```

or you could assign a tag to each button (there is  the property `android:tag`); and the you can retrieve it like:

```
Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interno_tavolo.class);
 extras.putString("one", (String)v.getTag());
activityChangeIntent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(activityChangeIntent)
```

Comment: Perfect. I did not know the Tag property

Answer (score 1):

If you have just number in button, make sure that all goes the same listener method,

and get the text and send the text as parameter.

```
public void ApriTavolo(View v) {
     Bundle extras = new Bundle();

     Button b = (Button) v;
     String value = b.getText().toString();

     // pass the value of button           
     extras.putString("value", value);

     // Perform action on click   
     Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interno_tavolo.class);
     activityChangeIntent.putExtras(extras);
     startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

}
```